# PyQt5 passing argument between two classes: lambda vs partial

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I am trying to pass an argument between two PyQt5 classes. I used three methods:

1. Using lambda functions.
2. Wrapper function (similar to lambda function).
3. `partial` from `functools` module.

In the example below, I have two windows:

- MainWindow has QLineEdit `mw_line_edit` and a QPushButton `mw_open_new_dialog_button`.
- Dialog: has a QLineEdit `line_edit` and aQPushButton `push_button`.

When I click the button `push_button`, I want it to insert the content of `line_edit` to `mw_line_edit`.

Here is a minimal example:

```
import sys
from functools import partial

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.mw_open_new_dialog_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Open New dialog', self)
        self.mw_line_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.hlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.hlayout.addWidget(self.mw_open_new_dialog_button)
        self.hlayout.addWidget(self.mw_line_edit)
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.hlayout)

        self.mw_open_new_dialog_button.clicked.connect(self.open_new_dialog)


    def open_new_dialog(self):
        self.dlg = Dialog()
        #self.dlg.clicked.connect(partial(self.write_something, self.dlg.line_edit.text())) # <<<<<<< This does not work
        self.dlg.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_something(self.dlg.line_edit.text())) # this works
        #self.dlg.clicked.connect(self.wrapper(self.dlg.line_edit.text()))# <<<<<<<<<<This does not work 
        self.dlg.exec()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def write_something(self, text):
        self.mw_line_edit.setText(text)

    def wrapper(self, text):
        return lambda: self.write_something(text)



class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QtWidgets.QDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.hlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.line_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.push_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Click me', self)
        self.hlayout.addWidget(self.line_edit)
        self.hlayout.addWidget(self.push_button)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('I am a Qlabel', self)
        self.hlayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(self.hlayout)
        self.push_button.clicked.connect(self.clicked)

    def write_something(self, text):
        print(text)



app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

main_window = MainWindow()
main_window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

As you can see in the commented lines, only the following method works:

`self.dlg.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_something(self.dlg.line_edit.text()))`

Why the other two do not work, i.e:

`self.dlg.clicked.connect(partial(self.write_something, self.dlg.line_edit.text())) # <<<<<<< This does not work`

`self.dlg.clicked.connect(self.wrapper(self.dlg.line_edit.text()))# <<<<<<<<<<This does not work`

Thanks

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @eyllanesc: I asked the question: Why partial and wrapper do not work

Comment: @eyllanesc: If I am trying to pass extra arguments to a slot in the same class, `partial` and `wrapper` both work but in my case with two classes why they do not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1) functools.partial()

**What arguments are you passing to partial?** You are passing the method `write_something` and the text of `self.dlg.line_edit` at the time the connection is made.

**And what is the value of that text?** it is an empty string, this explains the failure.

**Is there any solution for this case?** Yes, instead of passing the text, pass the QLineEdit, and in the method write_something get the text and set it in the other QLineEdit:

```
def open_new_dialog(self):
    self.dlg = Dialog()
    self.dlg.clicked.connect(partial(self.write_something, self.dlg.line_edit))
    self.dlg.exec()

def write_something(self, le):
    self.mw_line_edit.setText(le.text())
```

## 2) wrapper

It is the same problem, you are passing the empty text that you have at the moment of the connection

**Is there any solution?** Yes, the same solution as the previous one.

```
def open_new_dialog(self):
    self.dlg = Dialog()
    self.dlg.clicked.connect(self.wrapper(self.dlg.line_edit))
    self.dlg.exec()

def write_something(self, text):
    self.mw_line_edit.setText(text)

def wrapper(self, line):
    return lambda: self.write_something(line.text())
```

---

**Will there be a clean solution?** Yes, create a signal that transports the text when you click.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        self.mw_open_new_dialog_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Open New dialog')
        self.mw_line_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        hlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(central_widget)
        hlayout.addWidget(self.mw_open_new_dialog_button)
        hlayout.addWidget(self.mw_line_edit)
        self.mw_open_new_dialog_button.clicked.connect(self.open_new_dialog)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def open_new_dialog(self):
        self.dlg = Dialog()
        self.dlg.textSignal.connect(self.mw_line_edit.setText)
        self.dlg.exec()

class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    textSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QtWidgets.QDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        hlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.line_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.push_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Click me')
        hlayout.addWidget(self.line_edit)
        hlayout.addWidget(self.push_button)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('I am a Qlabel')
        hlayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.push_button.clicked.connect(self.sendText)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def sendText(self):
        self.textSignal.emit(self.line_edit.text())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: the `@QtCore.pyqtSlot()` decorator of `sendText` is necessary? I removed it and the program still work properly

Comment: @IamNotaMathematician read https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#the-pyqtslot-decorator